# I want to run a function for each product in a custom php file

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to run a function for each product in a custom php file in wordpress. I used foreach loop for the same. But unfotunately id didn't work. Need Help.

The code is:

```
<?php
require_once("../../../../wp-load.php");
global $product;

foreach($product as $offer){
update_views_meta($offer->id);
}
?>
```

Function runs when I put a perticular product id in the place of $offer->id. But can't fetch $product->id in this file.

Comment: you have to retrive via post loop it means post_type=>'Product'

Comment: I am very new to wordpress. So could you please tell me this in detail @Vasim Vanzara

Comment: what actually want?? what is your flow??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me...

```
<?php
$parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );
require_once( $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php' );
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'paged' => $paged,
    );
    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
$post_ids = wp_list_pluck( $wp_query->posts, 'ID' );
foreach ($post_ids as $offer) {
    your_function($offer);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a secondary loop and get all product from database using following code,

```
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'paged' => $paged,
    );
    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
    print_r($wp_query);
```

**Description:**

`post_type=>product` mean you want product from db.It returns all product as form of post array.all product in your hand you have to modify as per your need.That's it.